# How to swap windows using JIS keyboard

Tags: macos, keyboard

I have got a JIS keyboard layout recently, I always swap between windows using command + ` , now I have no idea how to do it.
Here is the layouts of two found on the internet.

[JIS and US keyboard layout](http://www.dtp-transit.jp/images/apple-keyboards-US-JIS.jpg)

Comment: JIS has keys for command and for `.  Shall we assume you have tried that combo and it doesn't work?

Comment: Yap, I have try everything I can with keyboard. The ` key is sharing with @, at the right side of the keyboard, I need to push shift button to type ` out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is one of the keys on the right side of the keyboard (like ろ or ￥) maybe backtick?

If not, you can remap some key to backtick with [KeyRemap4MacBook](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en). Save a file like this as `~/Library/Application Support/KeyRemap4MacBook/private.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <name>test</name>
    <identifier>test</identifier>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::JIS_UNDERSCORE, KeyCode::BACKQUOTE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::JIS_YEN, KeyCode::BACKQUOTE</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

Then open the KeyRemap4MacBook application, press the ReloadXML button, and tick the checkbox for the setting.

The shortcut for moving focus to the next window can also be changed from System Preferences:

[image]

Comment: the ` key is sharing the key with @ sign at right side of the keyboard :). I will checkout and try related settings when I'm home, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your information, I just forgot to checkout the shortcut settings. Turns out it use `command+F1` to focus on next window, for the MacBooks, need to combo with `fn` key.